# Separable spaces, need help

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Please if someone could tell me how to proof this below.

Problem: Is the space of continuous and bounded functions on $(-\infty,\infty)$, with the metric $d(x,y)=\sup\{|x(t)-y(t)|:t\in(-\infty,\infty)\}$ separable?

Where we can write $X=B(-\infty,\infty)\cap C(-\infty,\infty)$ where $B(-\infty,\infty)$ is the space of bounded functions on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $C (-\infty,\infty)$ the set of continuous functions on $(-\infty,\infty)$ as usual, so that $X$ is the set we are asking if it is separable.

I hope I've been clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can explicitly define a family of $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$ continuous functions into $[0,1]$, each two being $1$ away from one another in $\sup$ metric.

I think this is a good exercise to do on your own.

If you can't do that, see the hint below.

> First try to find such functions ${\bf N}\to \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I know I can define such a family on the space of bonded functions but on bonded and continuous I just cant come up with such a family.

Comment: @adoion: Keep trying. It's not that difficult, the basic idea is more or less the same.